# Find marginal expected value given joint pdf

Tags: probability

Joint pdf 
$f_{xy}(x,y) = 1$ if $0<x<1, x<y<x+1$, $0$ elsewhere

for $f(Y)$ I got $1$

for $E(Y)$ I got $\frac{1}{2}(2x+1)$, with limits of integration $(x,x+1)$

But I don't think this is correct because its in terms of $x$

Also, for $E(XY)$ I got $\frac{13}{24}$ with inner limits of integration $(x,x+1)$ and outer limits of integration $(0,1)$
Does that look right?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $f_Y^{\,}=0$ for $y \lt 0$ or $y \gt 2$, and it is not constant in between these.

You should be looking at something like $\displaystyle f_Y^{\,}(y) = \int f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \, dx$ and the skill is in determining the limits of integration (the values of $x$) where $f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y)$ is non-zero.

You will then be able to find $E[Y] = \displaystyle \int y f_Y^{\,}(y) \, dy$ and this will not depend on $x$.

Alternatively you could find $E[Y] = \displaystyle \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x}^{x+1} y f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \, dy\, dx$.

Meanwhile $E[XY] =  \displaystyle \int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=x}^{x+1} xy \,f_{X,Y}^{\,}(x,y) \, dy\, dx = \int_{x=0}^1 \frac{x \left( 2 x+1\right) }{2} \, dx =\frac7{12}.$

Answer (score 1):

At first let us check where is your Joint pdf is non zero, consider the following yellow colored region:[image]

Now to find the pdf of  $Y$, we have  $$ f(y)=\int f(x,y)dx$$
Since $f(x,y)$ is only non zero in the above yellow colored domin, so the iintegral is restricted to this domain. As it can be seen,  the variation of $x$ wrt $y$ in the domain is  as following:

- For  $0 < y< 1$,  we have   $ 0<x< y$.
- For $1\leq y<2$, we have  $y-1<x< 1$.

Thus  $$f(y)=\begin{cases} \int_0^y 1 dx \quad   \quad \text{ if }  0 < y< 1 \\   \quad \\
 \int_{y-1}^1 1 dx \quad   \quad   \text{ if } 1\leq y<2  \\
 \quad  \\
0 \quad  \quad  \quad   \quad   \text{ elsewhere} \end{cases}$$
Hence
$$f(y)=\begin{cases} y  \quad \quad   \quad \text{ if }  0 < y< 1 \\   \quad \\
1-y \quad   \quad   \text{ if } 1\leq y<2  \\
 \quad  \\
0 \quad  \quad  \quad   \quad   \text{ elsewhere} \end{cases}$$ 
I think from here you can easily find  $E[Y]=\int yf(y)dy $

Comment: do you mean (2,1) instead of (2,2)

Comment: @shoestringfries: I suspect $(1,2)$ for the top right corner

Comment: @Henry Thank you for pointing it !! also thanks  to shoestringfries !